# Why does setting multiple vals within a for expression not result in an exception?

Tags: scala

While playing around I noticed that setting a val within a for expression *does not* result in an exception.

For example :

```
  for (_ <- 1 to 100) {
    val foo = 10
    println(foo)
  }
```

I would have expected that trying to set a val multiple times would certainly result in an error. Why is that happening?

Comment: If you tried to assign to already created `var` you would get compile error, not an exception. You didn't so the scopes are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is legal code since you're creating `val` in the "iteration" body of `for`.

Your code is the same as the following and you can see why it's correct

```scala
(1 to 100).foreach { _ =>
  val foo = 10
  println(foo)
}
```

`val` is created in the scope of anonymous function `{ _ => }`